# CodeIgniter ionAuth library - cannot get the user object?

Tags: php, codeigniter, frameworks, authentication

I am using Codeigniter 2.1 with the latest version of IonAuth (http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth)

I am having a problem getting the user object using the method described in the documentation, in the previous version of IonAuth this worked fine - but now this doesn't seem to work - see the screenshots below to see what I mean.

All I am doing is just outputting this in the code :-

```
$this->ion_auth->user();
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong or is there a bug in the latest iteration of IonAuth?
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/138/outputofuserobjectnew.jpg/

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/26/outputofuserobjectold.jpg

P.S The first link is how it looks now - the latter link is how it used to look (grabbed from an existing project) - I know I could just downgrade the IonAuth to the older version but i'd prefer to keep it if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the usage here: http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/#user

Just add ->row() to your code and this will work, so instead of "$this->ion_auth->user();" you need to use "$this->ion_auth->user()->row();".

Comment: Awesome dude! You might want to update the docs to add the ->row() as this is what caught me out. Thanks though such a great class I use it for all my upcoming projects now :)